# Dont' charge customer until product ships - woocommerce

Tags: plugins

Is it possible to set woocommerce to not charge the customer until the product actually ships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much a WooCommerce issue as a payment gateway issue. Paypal distinguishes, for example, between 'authorization' and 'capture', Worldpay has similar terms (and a different API).

E.g. for Paypal see https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_authcapture.

In the case of Paypal, check https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_wpp_integrationguide.pdf:

Authorization and Capture API operations:
DoCapture
Capture an authorized payment.
DoAuthorization
Authorize a payment. (Express Checkout only)

So you probably need at least the Paypal Express Gateway plugin: http://www.woothemes.com/products/paypal-express/

Comment: @user715564 Did you end up using a paypal extension to solve this? If so, which?

Answer (score 1):

With Authorize.net AIM (http://www.woothemes.com/products/authorize-net-payment-gateway/) the "Sale Method" can be set to "Authorize Only" which will verify that funds are available on the customer's card, but not capture the funds. http://cld.wthms.co/afXJ

Then when the product ships the funds can be captured inside of the Authorize.net account dashboard. If funds are not captured within a few days the authorization will be released.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Advanced which is only $5 a month will do it. You will need an extension though to integrate unless you can code it yourself. IgniteWoo is the place I recommend for the extension - PayPal Payments Advanced. You can have the customer stay on your site or redirect to paypal page to pay. You may also need a SSL certificate for your site (if you stay on your page and don't redirect to paypal)
You have to sign up for a PayPal Advanced account....you also have several settings on PayPal Manager side that needs to be set correctly...

Answer (score 0):

I found this WooCommerce Module. You are able to authorize only and capture later if you like. It looks as if it works very well. See here http://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/wordpress-woocommerce-paypal-zahlungs-plugin.html

Comment: *[From the help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer):* Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.